# How do I deal with displacement or blink as a rogue?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, rogue

Both *blink* and *displacement* give my opponent a chance to completely evade my attacks (regardless of my attack roll) and prevent me from ever dealing sneak attack damage.

From 3.5e, I know that *true sight* (range: personal) and *dimensional anchor* (needs to hit first) are the correct replies, but our party is a little bit lacking in the spell department.

Is there any feat, mythic boon, or piece of equipment I can get myself to deal with this issue?

---

I'm playing a level 10 unchained rogue with the hidden blade archetype (granting me Path of War maneuvers from the Broken Blade, Mithral Current, Thrashing Dragon and Veiled Moon schools) in a mythic campaign (currently mythic 2).

Last game we faced a single level 9 wizard with *displacement* and *mirror image* and we only manage to hit her once or twice in the fourth round of combat, right before (having consumed all of her spell slots) she teleported away to safety after dealing tremendous damage.

---

Note: Much later, I realized that, as an unchained rogue, partial concealment is not enough to prevent my sneak attacks. The question is still good since it also focuses on completely missing the opponent, but just so you know... it's a bit less bad than it used to be.

Comment: Did you close your eyes?

Comment: @ShadowKras how does that help? You can't sneak attack something you can't see.

Comment: @Erik, its a joke. If you have no means to sneak attack what you cant see (total concealment), you also probably dont have the means to bypass blink and mirror images. The joke here is that you have a greater chance of landing an attack by *not seeing* your target due to how concealment works and the ruling on mirror images (visual illusions).

Comment: @ShadowKras we're currently deciding how much closing your eyes works, exactly because I tried overriding _mirror image_ with that.

Comment: @Zachiel Well *mirror image* at least explicitly says that closing your eyes works (but has other drawbacks).

Comment: @Kryan we're discussing about the things that ShadowKras details in their answer: can you selectively keep your eyes closed only while attacking (given the contemporarity of turns)? Is that too powerful/cheesy?

Comment: I've let PCs take free actions to close then open their eyes on their turns as per an extension of [gaze attacks](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Gaze_Su) on the example wearing a blindfold: "The foe cannot see the creature at all (also possible to achieve by turning one’s back on the creature or shutting one’s eyes)." I mean, we players just couldn't imagine it taking any *longer* than a free action to open or close one's eyes, especially since it seem averting—or not—one's eyes is a nonaction choice made during the acting creature's turn.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Blink* and *Mirror Images* is a very powerful combination against martial characters, you really had little that you could do in that situation. Fighting against such enemies requires planning and preparation. The only thing that you and your group could have done, without having prepared against this, is to have a *blanket* [Dispel Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic/) ready to remove his buffs.

However, get a [Truthful](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/truthful/) weapon if possible. A +1 Truthful Dagger (+3 total) should always be available from now on, or you risk finding yourself in a similar situation again when fighting outsiders and BBEG's again.

> A truthful weapon unerringly pierces concealment provided by illusions, allowing the wielder to ignore the miss chance provided by illusions such as blur, displacement, and invisibility. Attacks with a truthful weapon against a creature affected by mirror image or a similar figment always attack the real target.

[True Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-strike/) actually only works against concealment, it doesn't allow you to pierce illusions or the miss chance of ethereal creatures. But it does help against [Blur](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blur/), another common spell used in combination with *Mirror Images*.

And [Dimensional Anchor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimensional-anchor/) (or a [Phase Lock](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/phase-locking/) weapon) really doesn't help, unless you are really lucky and don't hit one of the images by accident. You would need to already be ignoring the spells's effects before anchoring the target.

### Closing your eyes

Due to how concealment and miss chances work, (*RAI*) you should never have more than 50% chance to miss a target, as [pointed out by James Jacobs](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kqkj?Blink-and-displacement#9) (Creative Director). So granting yourself blindness or a similar condition could help you against Mirror Images, while still maintaining the same miss chance.

However, there are no hard rules about how this works. We don't know if this is a free action, how long it lasts, if you can close your eyes before attacking, attack, then open again. Many community members are Paizo believe this is cheap, and a common house rule is to allow you to close your eyes, and accept the benefits (gaze attacks) and penalties that come with it (blindless) until the start of your next turn.

A (ex) [developer commented on this](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kca8?Scent-and-Mirror-Image#36), suggesting to spend a *Move Action* so you close your eyes and focus that the images are not really there, or your brain will still try to target one of the images because he couldn't really tell which one was real before closing his eyes. And this makes some sense, as you normally would need to [spend a move action to accurately perceive the location of an invisible creature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/129546/21153).

### Bring a shotgun to the fight

No, seriously. I know that some GM's don't allow [firearms](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/firearms/) in their games. But if you do, the [Scatter quality](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/firearms/#TOC-Firearm-Descriptions) of shotguns is not affected by the miss chance of *Mirror Images* or the concealment granted by *Blur* (should that situation arise in the future). This has been [confirmed](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2m0cv?Shotgun-vs-Mirror-Image#30) by Stephen Radney-MacFarland (designer):

> Effects like the mirror image spell, or effects that grant concealment, such as smoke, fog, or the blur or invisibility spells, do not foil a scatter shot attack.

Similarly, effects that affect an area should always help against *Mirror Images*. However, the miss chance from *Blink* is still there.

Comment: Low level dispels in PF only dispel the highest spell, which in that wizards' case was fire shield. Truthful seems awesome, and I think a splash effect from an acid flask could work too to damage and therefore "kill" all images. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I think that adding _displacement_ to miss chances that don't involve concealment (hitting the right mirror image, the _blink_ spell) makes for a total miss chance that's higher than 50%

Comment: @Zachiel this isn't official, but James Jacobs says [the limit should be 50%](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kqkj?Blink-and-displacement#9).

Comment: I had seen that post but I didn't realize it was from a designer. Still, I think mirror image is applied later.

Comment: Holy cow why have I never seen Truthful weapon before...

Comment: @Zachiel AoE (including Splash weapons) ignore Mirror Image and do not damage/remove them

Answer (score 0):

### Shadow Strike

This is a feat you can take when you have +1 BaB,

> You can deal precision damage, such as sneak attack damage, against targets with concealment (but not total concealment).

Its a feat any non-unchained Rogue should take. It is odd that Rogues in Pathfinder actually cannot effectively shank people in dark alleys, but this helps.